# How to send local URL from realtime-database to firebase storage?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have some issue with Firebase Storage,
I'm doing Sign up function to integration with real-time firebase and save some data Like " username, avatar, etc..
I use react native image picker to select images and send the response to a database as an object now I need to get this image and save them to Firebase Storage this is my code

image object :
[image: AvatarSource]

#### SignUp

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, TextInput, View, TouchableOpacity, Image } from "react-native";
import styles from "../Style/styles";
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";
import ImagePicker from "react-native-image-picker";

const options = {
  title: "Select Avatar",
  storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
    path: "images"
  }
};

export default class signUp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      username: "",
      avatarSource: "",
      errorMessage: null
    };
  }

  SignUpUser = (
    email,
    password,
    username,
    mobileNumber,
    city,
    avatarSource
  ) => {
    try {
      // if (this.state.password.length < 6) {
      //   alert("Please Enter At least 6 characters");
      //   return;
      // }
      // var userId = firebaseApp.auth().currentUser.uid;

      firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(user => {
          firebase
            .database()
            .ref(`users/${user.uid}`)
            .set({
              email: email,
              username: username,
              mobileNumber: mobileNumber,
              city: city
              avatarSource: avatarSource
            });
          // console.log("uid:", user);
          
          firebase.storage().ref(`UserAvatar/${avatarSource.data}`);

          this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.toString());
    }
  };

 
  handleAvatar = () => {
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
      console.log("Response = ", response);
      if (response.uri) {
        this.setState({ avatarSource: response });
      }
    });
  };
  render() {
    const { avatarSource } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{ color: "#e93766", fontSize: 40 }}>Sign Up</Text>
        {this.state.errorMessage && (
          <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>{this.state.errorMessage}</Text>
        )}
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleAvatar}>
        
          <Image
            source={{ uri: avatarSource.uri }}
            style={[styles.uploadAvatar, { borderRadius: 100 }]}
            resizeMode="cover"
          />

        
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Username"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          style={styles.textInput}
          onChangeText={username => this.setState({ username })}
          value={this.state.username}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Email"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          style={styles.textInput}
          onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
          value={this.state.email}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="City"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          style={styles.textInput}
          onChangeText={city => this.setState({ city })}
          value={this.state.city}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Mobile Number"
          keyboardType="numeric"
          style={styles.textInput}
          onChangeText={mobileNumber => this.setState({ mobileNumber })}
          value={this.state.mobileNumber}
          maxLength={10}
        />
        <TextInput
          secureTextEntry
          placeholder="Password"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          style={styles.textInput}
          onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
          value={this.state.password}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() =>
            this.SignUpUser(
              this.state.email,
              this.state.password,
              this.state.username,
              this.state.mobileNumber,
              this.state.city,
              this.state.avatarSource
            )
          }
        >
          <Text style={{ color: "#e93766", fontSize: 18 }}>Sign Up </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
       
        <View>
          <Text>
            
            Already have an account?
            <Text
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")}
              style={{ color: "#e93766", fontSize: 18 }}
            >
              
              Login
            </Text>
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think your problem is clear, can you be more precise?

Comment: Hmm, I want to upload an image from my mobile to our firebase storage good? but now I'm saving them into real-time DB, as you see in the screenshot I need to get this image and save them to firebase storage

Comment: Why do you have to move it from the realtime db to the storage? Can't you upload it to the storage directly?

Comment: Idk :D, I write one function to sign up and save custom data and contained the avatar into real-time DB, and when I press the sign up button I'm calling this function once, so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload a file to Storage, use `put` on your storage ref.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files):

```
var file = ... // use the Blob or File API
ref.put(file).then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
});
```

In your case, it will look something like the following. Please make sure you understand what each line of the code is actually doing.

It looks like your file is just a blob, so use the Blob API as mentioned in the docs.

```
let file = // whatever your file is
let path = // whatever the path you want in Storage is.
           // if it does not exist yet, you will need to create it.
let ref = firebase.storage().ref('UserAvatar/' + path);
ref.put(file).then(snapshot => {console.log('done')});
```

Comment: I'm read this but I cant manipulate this in my Function, can you manipulate them to my code, I have some stuck?

Comment: The output of this: `firebase.storage().ref(\`UserAvatar/${avatarSource.data}\`);` is your storage ref. That's what you'll `put` the file to.

Comment: That documentation page is pretty detailed, have a look

Comment: sadly doesn't work, I do that,

  let storage = firebase.storage();
          let file = firebase.storage().ref(`UserAvatar/${avatarSource.data}`);
          console.log(file);
          storage.ref.put(file).then(function(snapshot) {
            console.log("Uploaded a blob or file!" + snapshot);
          });

Comment: the error is " TypeError: storage.ref.put is not a function "

Comment: That's not correct. The ref is not the file. You need to call `put` on the variable that you're currently calling `file`.

Comment: hmm, I do not understand this, the file is the ref(`UserAvatar/${avatarSource.data}`) ? you said the output of them its a file :/

Comment: All you're doing there is creating a reference to a node in Cloud Storage at the path described by that string. You will then take your file, wherever it is, and send it to that ref. See clarified answer above

Comment: can you open chat with me? please

Comment: it's done, I'm really stuck because I'm new with Firebase, when I do that
{
 let file = avatarSource.uri; 
 let path = avatarSource.path;
} it's ok but the path in the Storage its too long,
like this "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20190313_120325.jpg" , how just cut this and use the ref "AvatarUser/IMG_12012.png" ?

Comment: I would recommend creating a consistent path structure based on user IDs, something like '/user/12345/avatar/img.png'